# Why WTSRegisterSessionNotification may fail with Access Denied error?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, pascal

I receiving a few bug reports from users which contains a strange error. On some machines (Windows 10 and 8.1) calling WTSRegisterSessionNotification returns Error code 5 (Access Denied):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FWTSNotification: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); override;
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWindowHandle; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.CreateWnd; 
begin
  inherited;
  FWTSNotification:= WTSRegisterSessionNotification(Handle, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION);
  if not FWTSNotification
  then
  begin
   var FLastError:= GetLastError;
   Raise Exception.Create(Format('WTSRegisterSessionNotification failed: [ErrorCode: #%d] - %s', [FLastError, SysErrorMessage(FLastError)]));
  end;
end;

...

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin

 case Msg.Msg of

  WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
  begin
   case Msg.wParam of
    WTS_SESSION_LOCK: ...
    WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK: ...
    WTS_CONSOLE_CONNECT: ...
    WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT: ...
   end;
  end;

 else
  inherited;
 end;
end;

...

procedure TForm1.DestroyWindowHandle;
begin
 if FWTSNotification
 then WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(Handle);
 inherited;
end;
```

I tried to reproduce this bug on my computers with windows 10, 8, 7, accounts with admin\user rights, but has never got any errors. What could be the reason of this error and how to reproduce it?

Comment: Windows are subject to recreation. They second time createwnd is called it will fail. To Solve this create a separate window with [allocatehwnd](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd) and put your winproc there.

Comment: @whosrdaddy the code is handling window recreation properly, by unregistering the old window before it is destroyed, and then registering the new window after it is created. That is not the problem. That being said, I do agree that using a single persistent window may make more sense. I probably would have used the `TApplication` window instead of `AllocateHwnd` (no need to make a new window when you already have one just hanging around), but either would work

Comment: Ah I see, I missed the destroywindowhandle part. :)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau do you mean I should use WTSRegisterSessionNotification(Application.Handle, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION) instead of WTSRegisterSessionNotification(Handle, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION)?

Comment: @Tigero that will work, yes. And then you can use `TApplication.HookMainWindow()` to catch the `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` messages. That window is never recreated once it is created. Or, you can use `AllocateHwnd()` instead, like whosrdaddy suggested. Either will work